# solve inequality geometrically

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$ and  $g(x)=-x^2+x$

1. Plot $f$ and $g$
2. Solve geometrically that $f(x)\leq g(x)$

Indeed,

$D_{f}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$ and $D_{g}=\mathbb{R}$

1. by using geogebra i got

[image]

2. geometrically i got

\begin{align}
f(x)\leq g(x) \iff S=(-1,1]
\end{align}

wolframe gives me $S=(-1,1]$ but i don't know how to got that geometrically

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: What is f(-2)?  Something happens at x=-1 that you have not accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph show clearly why should be ,1]

For the (-1  part you forget f(x) has another part for x<-1

For x<-1, f(x) will be all positive since the top and bottom of f(x) are negative, which is always >g(x). If you plot that part you can see this clearly